# Option "daysOfWeekDisabled" not working in bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Here it is html I have been using for getting Bootstrap datetimepicker to disable weekend days:

```js
$('.datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm',
  pickSeconds: false
});
$('.datetimepicker4').datetimepicker('setDate', (new Date()));
$('.datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-append datetimepicker4">
  <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="text">
  <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an old version of datetimepicker you are using, `daysOfWeekDisabled` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`daysOfWeekDisabled` does not exist in that version of bootstrap-datetimepicker

I suggest using the original DateTimePicker on which Tarruda is based, the one made by [Stefan Petre](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Here is an example : [Simple Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://ibootstrap.net/Snippets/IDXBkU5/Simple-DateTimePicker)